# Filter list using lambda expressions

Tags: c#, .net-4.5

The below method returns all the `System.Type` classes from the namespace we have specified.
However, I don't want all, I would like to be able to retrieve only the type that I want. Say I want the type `INMIRegisterRepository`. How to filter the below list for this? Please help.

```
public static List<Type> TypesInNameSpace(Assembly assembly, string nameSpace)
{
    return assembly
            .GetTypes()
            .Where(O => string.Equals(O.Namespace, nameSpace, StringComparison.Ordinal))
            .ToList();
}
```

Comment: Do you understand how this code works?

Answer (score 0):

```
var Item =  assembly
               .GetTypes()
               .FirstOrDefault(O => string.Equals(O.Namespace, 
                                       "INMIRegisterRepository",
                                        StringComparison.Ordinal));
```

Or if you want to access the returned list then:

```
var yourList = TypesInNameSpace(......

var Item = yourList.FirstOrDefault(O => string.Equals(O.Namespace, 
                                           "INMIRegisterRepository",
                                            StringComparison.Ordinal));
```

Comment: I want List<Type> objects finally because our method expects List<Type> objects. when i use the below I am getting exception - Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Type' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Type>'  : Code :   List<Type> lockCaches = types.FirstOrDefault(O => string.Equals(O.Namespace,
                                                             "INMIRegisterRepository",
                                                             StringComparison.Ordinal));

Answer (score 0):

Just use the [Assembly.GetType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.gettype.aspx):

```
assembly.GetType("INMIRegisterRepository");
```

Using Lambda expression you can do:

```
assembly.GetTypes().Where(t => t.GetType() == typeof(INMIRegisterRepository))
```

Comment: *Assembly* is not  Enumerable